# Is there a way to simulate upcoming invoice amount in Laravel Cashier without updating quantity on Stripe?

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I'm using Laravel Cashier for subscription management in my Laravel application, and I want to provide users with an estimate of the upcoming invoice amount if they were to increase their subscription quantity. However, I don't want to actually update the quantity on Stripe until the user confirms the change. Is there a way to simulate the upcoming invoice amount without updating the quantity on Stripe using Laravel Cashier or any functionality provided by Stripe? Any suggestions or simple solutions would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: i think there is not a functionality provided by stripe that shows you an invoice if the user was to upgrade, that would have to be all custom code i believe

Answer (score 0):

Stripe provides an API to preview upcoming invoices. You can learn more about it [here](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/invoices/subscription#previewing).